# How do I redirect all the IP addresses going to 185.38.31.85 to 185.38.31.82 on my Windows machine?

Tags: windows-10, ip, nat, ip-address

I tried modifying the /etc/hosts file with the following entry but it doesn't work. I am on Windows 10. I would like to redirect the ones below to go to 82

```
185.38.31.83 185.38.31.82
       ...84 185.38.31.82
       ...85 185.38.31.82
```

Comment: Is your computer on `185.38.31.85`? Please explain your network architecture.

Comment: @harrymc the computer is not on that ip address, i have an external exe program that connects randomly to one of these 4 ip addresses, 3 of them dont work so I want to block them or redirect them to the working one which is the one ending with 82

Comment: Are you an administrator of the computer where this program is located?

Comment: @harrymc yes, this is not windows server, it is normal windows 10 os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to proxify the program as to divert all references from
the bad IPs to the good one.

A well-known (commercial) product is
[Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/)
($39.95 with 31-day Free Trial).

A couple of free and open-source alternatives found by google :

- [WinDivert](https://www.reqrypt.org/windivert.html)
- [proxify](https://github.com/projectdiscovery/proxify)